# Newbie difficulties with graphicsmagick and jpeg decode delegates

Tags: terminal, jpeg, homebrew, graphicsmagick

I am having difficulty trying to get graphicsmagick to work. New to the coding world =]

I think I might have botched up my installation by not using brew to install.

I have an image on my /Desktop; 'sign.jpeg'

Here's what I get when I try to identify (or resize) the image:

```
Admins-iMac:Desktop admin$ gm identify sign.jpeg
gm identify: No decode delegate for this image format (sign.jpeg).
gm identify: Request did not return an image.
```

So I guess I will try unlinking and relinking:

```
Admins-iMac:Desktop admin$ brew unlink jpeg
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b... 17 symlinks removed

Admins-iMac:Desktop admin$ brew link jpeg
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b... 17 symlinks created
```

Hmm:

```
Admins-iMac:Desktop admin$ brew info jpeg
jpeg: stable 9b (bottled)
Image manipulation library
http://www.ijg.org
/usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/9b (20 files, 724KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-01-11 at 10:48:47
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/jpeg.rb
```

Alright so I guess I will try un/reinstalling graphicsmagick:

```
Admins-iMac:Desktop admin$ brew uninstall imagemagick graphicsmagick libpng jpeg
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick
```

Let me check the version info:

```
Admins-iMac:Desktop admin$ gm -version
GraphicsMagick 1.3.27  Q8 http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 GraphicsMagick Group.
Additional copyrights and licenses apply to this software.
See http://www.GraphicsMagick.org/www/Copyright.html for details.

Feature Support:
  Native Thread Safe       yes
  Large Files (> 32 bit)   yes
  Large Memory (> 32 bit)  yes
  BZIP                     yes
  DPS                      no
  FlashPix                 no
  FreeType                 no
  Ghostscript (Library)    no
  JBIG                     no
  JPEG-2000                no
  JPEG                     no
  Little CMS               no
  Loadable Modules         no
  OpenMP                   no
  PNG                      no
  TIFF                     no
  TRIO                     no
  UMEM                     no
  WebP                     no
  WMF                      no
  X11                      no
  XML                      yes
  ZLIB                     yes

Host type: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0

Configured using the command:
  ./configure  'CC=clang' 'LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/libjpeg/lib -L/usr/local/libpng/lib -L/usr/local/libtiff/lib' 'CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/libjpeg/include -I/usr/local/libpng/include -I/usr/local/libtiff/include' '--prefix=/usr/local/mac-dev-env/graphicsmagick-1.3.27'

Final Build Parameters:
  CC       = clang
  CFLAGS   = -g -O2 -Wall -D_THREAD_SAFE
  CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/libjpeg/include -I/usr/local/libpng/include -I/usr/local/libtiff/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
  CXX      = g++
  CXXFLAGS = -D_THREAD_SAFE
  LDFLAGS  = -L/usr/local/libjpeg/lib -L/usr/local/libpng/lib -L/usr/local/libtiff/lib -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk/usr/lib
  LIBS     = -lbz2 -lxml2 -lz -lm -lpthread
```

I am just not good with this terminal stuff quite yet, so I am mostly unsure how to interpret all these lines. I should have just used brew to install it in the first place D:

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any particular reason to use **GraphicsMagick** rather than **ImageMagick** which is IMHO a more comprehensive, further evolved and more  popular product?

Comment: The comment above is  not meant to be inflammatory, and is based on experience & evidence. **GraphicsMagick** is missing several critical features - not least of which are the ability to do parenthesised *"aside processing"*, cloning, swapping, decent alpha handling. My popularity comment relates to there being 6,500 questions on **ImageMagick** on StackOverflow vs 550 on **GraphicsMagick**. Yes, you could argue that means the former is harder to understand or more poorly documented - I suppose, but as I said I am not trying to start an argument. I know which one I'd take to a desert island.

Comment: Honestly, whichever I can get to work first would be what I would try to use haha.

Comment: I went ahead and tried installing imagemagick, and was able to get things to work pretty effortlessly. I was afraid that after botching up the graphicsmagick installation that I would have issues when trying to remove or uninstall anything. I just installed imagemagick and was able to start using it right away without much trouble at all, and didn't even bother with trying to uninstall graphicsmagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would recommend **ImageMagick** over **GraphicsMagick**, with reasons as in the comments above.

To sort out your current situation, I would do the following:

- ensure my `PATH` is correct for **homebrew**
- uninstall all the mentioned packages
- install the necessary packages
- check my setup

So, I'll cover each  aspect of that with a separate section, and put a horizontal rule in between.

---

Edit your login profile, probably `$HOME/.profile` and make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is at the start because that is where **homebrew** installs stuff. So basically, you want a line near the end like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Exit Terminal, and then start a new Terminal and check your PATH starts correctly with `/usr/local/bin` by running:

```
echo $PATH
```

---

Now remove all the packages you have been playing with:

```
brew rm imagemagick jpeg libpng graphicsmagick
```

---

Now reinstall just the ones you want:

```
brew install jpeg libpng imagemagick
```

---

Now test that **homebrew** is happy, by running:

```
brew doctor
```

and following the good doctor's advice.

Then you should be able to run:

```
identify -version
convert -size 1024x768 gradient:red-blue first.jpg
```

You can see the created image by opening the Finder at the current directory:

```
open .
```

Then select the file with the mouse by tapping on it once, and press the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> bar to quick-look it.

Comment: Thank you for the imagemagick suggestion and the setup help here. I was able to get imagemagick to work with no problems. I'm just gonna forget about graphicsmagick for now...

Answer (score 0):

I've been having issues with Homebrew's `1.3.27` version of GraphicsMagick - it doesn't seem to configure the delegates properly.

Downgrading to `1.3.26_2` has solved our issues.

Comment: How do I go about downgrading? I'd like to give it a try.